# SVN Diff of two files with different extension

Tags: svn, netbeans, version-control, diff, netbeans-8.1

I'm using SVN integrated with NetBeans 8.1.

I'm translating a bunch of HTML file in JSP, so the former are very similar to the latter.

I want to compare the JSP I just created with its corresponding HTML in the repository.

Is this possible? Because SVN doesn't display the HTML in the diff view, saying:

> content not avaible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it possible. Just run `svn diff --old <URL> --new <URL>`. I'm not sure whether there is such capability built-in to NetBeans.

Make sure that you use Subversion 1.8 or newer client and read the documentation on [`svn diff`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html).

For related options in TortoiseSVN client, check [its manual's Viewing Differences section](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-diff.html).

Comment: And using TortoiseSVN GUI is possible? The command work via prompt, but without highlighting is impossible to understand something.

Comment: Checkout a working copy, **press and hold** Shift, right-click the file and then select TortoiseSVN | Diff with URL. Try other options, as well.

Comment: `If you want to see the differences between two different files, you can do that directly in explorer by selecting both files (using the usual Ctrl-modifier). Then from the explorer context menu select TortoiseSVN → Diff.` This does exactly what I want. Thank you for reminding me the importance of manuals.